# Simple logger class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I've been using logging libraries recently and somebody told me to try and write my own. I've kept it minimal but the only drawback is I can't log in static classes, due to TClass.

---

[Follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195304/simple-logger-class-in-c-follow-up)

---

I'm looking for constructive criticism on how to improve it.

How do I declare a logger variable?

```
private static readonly Logger<CatalogController> Logger = new Logger<CatalogController>();
```

I guess another drawback is that its pretty long, including the class name (twice) and then all the access modifiers and class names of the logger, it an get pretty ugly.

```
public class Logger <TClass>
{
    private readonly Type _className;

    public Logger()
    {
        _className = typeof(TClass);
    }

    public void Trace(string message, bool log = false)
    {
        Log(message, ConsoleColor.White, log);
    }

    public void Warn(string message, bool log = false)
    {
        Log(message, ConsoleColor.Yellow, log);
    }

    public void Debug(string message, bool log = false)
    {
        Log(message, ConsoleColor.Cyan, log);
    }

    public void Success(string message, bool log = false)
    {
        Log(message, ConsoleColor.Green, log);
    }

    public void Error(string message, bool log = false)
    {
        Log(message, ConsoleColor.Red, log);
    }

    public void Error(Exception e)
    {
        Log("An error occurred: " + Environment.NewLine + e, ConsoleColor.Red);
    }

    private void Log(string message, ConsoleColor color, bool log = false)
    {
        var oldColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now:MM/dd HH:mm:ss}] " + message);
        Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;

        string logFile;

        switch (color)
        {
            case ConsoleColor.Yellow:
                logFile = "error.log";
                break;
            case ConsoleColor.Cyan:
                logFile = "debug.log";
                break;
            case ConsoleColor.Red:
                logFile = "error.log";
                break;
            default:
                logFile = "trace.log";
                break;
        }

        LogToFile(logFile, $"Occurred at [{DateTime.Now:MM/dd HH:mm:ss}] in [{_className.FullName}]: " + message);
    }

    private static void LogToFile(string file, string content)
    {
        var executionPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(executionPath + "/resources/logging/" + file, true);

        fileWriter.WriteLine(content);
        fileWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise you check a few of the existing ones to get some ideas. If you're going to reinvent the wheel, at least look at the existing ones for some tips.

Comment: You've already posted a follow-up - in this case, it'd be nice if you could accept the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 3):

I have two notes to make here,

1. Extract a public interface from this code, like `ILogger<T>`, and store (or inject) an `ILogger<T>` instead of a `Logger<T>`

This will allow you to create different implementations of your logger type and pass it to the consumers of your logger without them knowing/caring whether it's logging to a console, to a file, or to a typewriter.

An important use case for that is creating an `ILogger` implementation for unit tests. You probably don't want your unit tests to have any side effects, so you could create a `TestLogger` class that implements `ILogger` and records all the logs to a list instead of a to a file or console.

2. Handle write access in a safer way

Currently you are not disposing of your StreamWriter instance. Even though you are calling `Close` you really should be either using a `using` statement or having a single instance of the stream writer that is accessed through an actor or other thread safe method and is disposed when your logger is disposed.

(Less important, but I would also store the execution path in a `static readonly`

```
private static readonly string executionPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "/resources/logging/" + file;

private static void LogToFile(string file, string content)
{
    using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(executionPath, true))
    {
        fileWriter.WriteLine(content);
        fileWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that it may not be desirable to reopen a stream for every log message that is written. It depends on the log, an exception log that is going to rarely be written to shouldn't be kept open; but a trace log that receives a massive load (e.g. during a processing job) will benefit from reusing the same stream. You may want to make this behavior configurable so you can use either.